# Изменить отступ элементов в QCalendarWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qcalendarwidget

Я использую *PyQt5* + *Qt Designer*.

Мне необходимо получить из этого

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что то похожее на:

[image: извините за исполнение]

Comment: что за элементы управления то? таблица/кнопки...

Comment: Думаю, что это таблица, хотя они кликабельны

Comment: Вы можете наследовать данный виджет и переопределить защищенный метод `paintCell` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcalendarwidget.html#paintCell, именно в нем и происходит прорисование ячейки календаря

Comment: Можете привести пример кода?

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_custom_calender_widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class CalendarWidget(QCalendarWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CalendarWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setVerticalHeaderFormat(self.NoVerticalHeader)
        
    def paintCell(self, painter, rect, date):
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        QCalendarWidget.paintCell(self, painter, rect, date)
        pen = QPen(QColor(128, 128, 128), 10)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawRect(rect)


qss = '''
QCalendarWidget QToolButton {
    width: 150px;
}
#qt_calendar_navigationbar {
    max-height: 0px;
}
/* header row */
QCalendarWidget QWidget { 
    alternate-background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128); 
}
/* normal days */
QCalendarWidget QAbstractItemView:enabled {
    font-size:24px;  
    color: rgb(180, 180, 180);  
    background-color: black;  
    selection-background-color: rgb(64, 64, 64); 
    selection-color: rgb(0, 255, 0); 
}
QCalendarWidget QAbstractItemView:disabled { 
    color: rgb(0, 64, 64); 
}
'''
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(qss)
    w = CalendarWidget()
    w.resize(500, 450)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое вам!

Comment: @Sergievsky пожалуйста